# SWF Upload and jquery

Tags: jquery, swfupload

I'm using swfupload to upload a file. The problem is that when I upload an image, it refreshes the page. What I want is when the user uploads an image, it shows the image on the uploaded page.

How can I do this? 
Can I use jQuery to prevent from refresh ?

Comment: Check out [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) - might interest you.

Answer (score 1):

swfupload do not refresh the page by itself ... you have to implement code in callback and change the image src as the upload completed ... without you show your code i cannot say too much else